# How do I search for a combined term across multiple columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a database with columns like so

```
| streetname | housenumber | afterslash | 
| ---------- | ----------- | ---------- |
| Mystreet   | 10          | 1          |
| Mystreet   | 10          | 2          |
| Mystreet   | 13          | 20         |
| Mystreet   | 40          | 22         |
| Mystreet   | 100         | 10         |
```

Considering the search term may be `Mystreet 10` I would like to

`SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE streetname+(housenumber or afterslash) LIKE 'Mystreet 10'`

and the intended result should be

```
| wholeaddress    | 
| --------------- |
| Mystreet 10/1   |
| Mystreet 10/2   |
| Mystreet 100/10 |
```

but for the search term `Mystreet 1` the result should be

```
| wholeaddress    | 
| --------------- |
| Mystreet 10/1   |
| Mystreet 10/2   |
| Mystreet 13/20  |
| Mystreet 100/10 |
```

because all these rows have a beginning 1 in the `housenumber` and/or `afterslash`.

How do I search for a term across multiple columns and return a (pre-formatted?) result?

Comment: In MySQL `+` is addition operator, not concatenation one. Use CONCAT() function.

Comment: Yep, that was just an example.

Comment: Approximate example may result in approximate answer... I'd recommend you to provide source data as online fiddle or (CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts) for 2 tables - your data table with ~10 rows, and 1-column table with "search terms" with ~3  rows, and desired matching output table. This allows both to see the variations and to try this on the fiddle for to refine the solution.

Answer (score 0):

For example, the query may be

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(streetname, ' ', housenumber, '/', afterslash)
FROM addresses 
WHERE CONCAT(streetname, ' ', housenumber) LIKE CONCAT(@search_term, '%')
```